# How to detect skin color (Black, Brown, White)?

Tags: c++, opencv

Suppose that a face image detected from haar cascade as an example is given. How to detect the color of the skin (Black, Brown, White)?

Comment: what's about red and yellow? ;D

Comment: `std::cin >> skinColor`

Comment: Please, don't color fight me :D

Comment: @quantdev I'm saving that as a last choice.

Comment: I would look at RGB values, write them down, then figure the differences between all 3.

Comment: My computer doesn't see skin color.

Comment: first you should normalize the image to remove colored-light effects. then you can use HSV color values to decide.

Comment: What do you mean by "white", "brown", and "black"?  If you are trying to do racial classification, be aware that there are plenty of southern Europeans who have darker skin than people who identify as African-Americans, so the actual HLS values aren't going to help much.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you two options:
1. Use neural networks. For this you need to train NN. I can assume that perceptron will be enough. 
2. Sum of all pixels of different colors of skin will be in different ranges. The smallest will be range of black. The second will be brown. The third or biggest will be White

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a mixture of Gaussians approach.

Model each of the three categories {Black, Brown, White} as a mixture of two or three Guassians in HSV space or CIELab space. You would learn these using an expectation maximization algorithm.